# amazon price web scraping with python, requests and bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a question about web scraping the price of an amazon article. I tried to get the price of an article and it works unfortunately not always. I get randomly the status code 503 (server unavailable). I can work around that problem with a while loop that ends if status code == 200. 
I want to understand the main problem of the unavailable server, so I can maybe fix the main problem and not work around of it. The problem occurs only on amazon so far.

here is my code for a 10 times test. The request usually fails 2/10 times

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for i in range(10):
    page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.de/Bloodborne-Game-Year-PlayStation-4/dp/B016ZU4FIQ/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1519566642&sr=8-3&keywords=bloodborne+ps4")

    if page.status_code != 200:
        print("Error status code: " + str(page.status_code))
        continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice", class_="a-size-medium a-color-price")


    price_string = price.get_text()

    print(price_string)
```

Comment: Amazon deliberately thwarts scraping its frontend. It's also a violation of their TOS to scrape the site like that, consider using their API instead if possible. It is likely that Amazon is throttling the number of requests you are allowed to make and/or blocking based on user-agent. You *may* get better results if you add a browser user-agent header to your request.

Comment: Okay, I wanted to scrap that for my own practice. im a python beginner and it was only a little price alarm :) thanks for your answer

Comment: @sytech which APIs are you talking about? If you mean the "Product Advertising API" they are not available for "normal" users. Look here: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/register-for-pa-api.html

Comment: @mastupristi if APIs you need are not provided, then that's pretty much the end of the story if you are to abide by the Terms of Service. Scraping product pages, in general, is likely a violation of the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below script. It should get you the price.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.de/Bloodborne-Game-Year-PlayStation-4/dp/B016ZU4FIQ/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1519566642&sr=8-3&keywords=bloodborne+ps4"
page = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
print(price)
```

Output:

```
EUR 34,99
```

Comment: I tried this bit of code but I guess Amazon has a new policy now since I get this in the output : '<body>
<!--
        To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.de/ref=rm_c_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://partnernet.amazon.de/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac for advertising use cases.
-->'

Answer (score 0):

it's old but for anyone trying this:

you should use user-agent, here is the example code

```
headers = {
            myuseragent
                   }

        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

you can find your user agent in here

[user-agent](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=my%20user%20agent&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)