# why i keep getting none or empty lists when trying to scrape any data with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

im trying to extract a simple title of a product from amazon.com using the id that the span which contains the title has.
this is what i wrote:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Acer-SB220Q-Ultra-Thin-Frame-Monitor/dp/B07CVL2D2S/ref=lp_16225007011_1_7'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
print(title)
```

and i keep getting either none or empty list or i cant extract anything and gives me an attribute error saying that the object i used doesnt have an attribute get_text, which raised another question which is how to get the text of this simple span.
i really appreciate it if someone could figure it out and help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the content of the response. It might help you understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Running your code and checking the `res` value, you would get a 503 error. This means that the Service is unavailable ([htttp status 503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503)).

#### Solution

Following up, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992650/amazon-price-web-scraping-with-python-requests-and-bs4) SO post, seems that adding the `headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"}` to the `get` requests does work.

```
res = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Defined"})
```

Will return a 200 (OK) response.

#### The Twist

Amazon actually checks for web scrapers, and even though you will get a page back, printing the result (`print(soup)`) will likely show you the following:

```
<body>
<!--
        To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_c_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac for advertising use cases.
-->

...

<h4>Enter the characters you see below</h4>
<p class="a-last">Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

#### The counter

But you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to simulate a human. A minimal working example for me was the following:

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'http://www.amazon.com/Acer-SB220Q-Ultra-Thin-Frame-Monitor/dp/B07CVL2D2S/ref=lp_16225007011_1_7'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
title = driver.find_element_by_id('productTitle').text
print(title)
```

Which prints out

```
Acer SB220Q bi 21.5 Inches Full HD (1920 x 1080) IPS Ultra-Thin Zero Frame Monitor (HDMI & VGA Port), Black
```

A small thing when using selenium is that it is much slower than the `requests` library. Also a new screen will pop-up that shows the page, but luckily we can do something about that screen by using a `headless` driver.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will learn selenium in the near future for automation and i will try it for scrapping since it seems like i cant get anything done with beautifullsoup

Comment: Nowadays more and more companies are using Javascript and Anti bot software. Selenium is a development tool that is meant to be similar to a human. Therefore it can interact with the JS and (often) bypass the anti-bot software. The trouble I had with installing selenium is that you need to install `selenium` (any case `pip install selenium`), but also a driver component dependent on your browser, for example [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for Firefox and [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) for chrome. Besides that, easy peasy.